# i wish to use my Apeman A77 as Webcam, can't find drivers

Tags: software-installation

i can't find a link for drivers to recognize my action cam. i want to use it as a webcam. It does recognize the camera as a mass storage, the sd card.

Comment: By the way i am concerned with my pc not a laptop.

Comment: I have it working here as a webcam but I can't have it as a wide angle.

Comment: the A77 does not support the web cam featuers ? which is all I purchased it for....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for any drivers, just press the top button once it's connected to the PC, and it sets itself as PC camera, Linux automatically recognizes it as an UVC device (iCatchtek SPCA6350).

Comment: Yes, thank you. what my issue was i had to take out my sd card, as soon as i did it started working. Thank you again.

Comment: @Vincent-Michael Thank you for that comment. After trying to find out what is wrong with my A80, I removed the SD card and it finally transmits video to the PC.